# Yii model relation one-to-newest

Tags: orm, yii, model

Assume we have 3 tables like this:

```
---------    ---------------    -------------------
| USER  |    | USER_STATUS |    | STATUS_DICT     |
|-------|    |--------------    |------------------
| id    |    | id          |    | id (int)        |
| name  |    | user_id     |    | status (string) |
| email |    | status_id   |    -------------------
---------    | timestamp   |
             ---------------
```

Each `user` has many statuses (`user_status`), related with `user.id <-> user_status.user_id`. Each `user_status` has one related record in `status_dict` which is string label of int status (for example 0 = active).

What I want is make User model to retrieve last user's status using relation. Set relations:

```php
/* User model */
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'status' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'UserStatus', 'user_id', 'order'=>'status.id DESC'),
    );
}
```

and

```php
/* UserStatus model */
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'status' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'StatusDictionary', 'status_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
    );
}
```

Then when I call `User::model()->findByPk(1)->status` I get latest status for user #1.

BUT.

When I want to find all users with specified status it does not work as I want. Instead of getting only users with specified status (latest record in `user_status`) I get all users who at least once had this status.

What I have to do to make relation one-to-newest (I call it like this for this case's purpose)? I saw [this article](http://murrayhopkins.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/mysql-left-join-on-last-or-first-record-in-the-right-table/) and it does the job, but I'm wondering if there is way to achieve it with Yii's conventions.

I wanted to declare named scope like this:

```php
/* in User model */
public function withStatus($status) {
    if(!is_numeric($status) && !is_null($status)) {
        $status = StatusDictionary::model()->find('lower(name)=lower(:name)', array(':name' => $status))->getAttribute('id');
    }

    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition' => (is_null($status) ? 'status.status_id IS NULL' : 'status.status_id=:statusId'),
        'params' => array(':statusId' => $status),
        'with' => array('status')
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

But it doesn't work either, `User::model()->withStatus(0)->findAll()` returns all users with related record in `user_status` with `user_status.status_id = 0` even if some of users have newer, different status.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found solution with TheRifler's help from his post. It turned out that I had a solution right under my nose (article linked in a question).

Relation should be defined as below:

```php
/* User model */
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'status' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'UserStatus', 'user_id',
            'order' => 's.id DESC',
            'alias' => 's',
            // http://murrayhopkins.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/mysql-left-join-on-last-or-first-record-in-the-right-table/
            'join' => 'LEFT JOIN ( SELECT s1.*
                        FROM `user_status` as s1
                        LEFT JOIN `user_status` AS s2
                        ON s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.id < s2.id
                        WHERE s2.user_id IS NULL ) as `status`
                        ON (s.user_id = `status`.user_id)'
            ),
    );
}
```

and the named scope:

```php
public function withStatus($status) {
    if(!is_numeric($status) && !is_null($status)) {
        $status = StatusDictionary::model()->find('lower(name)=lower(:name)', array(':name' => $status))->getAttribute('id');
    }

    $this->with('status');
    if(!is_null($status)) {
        $this->getDbCriteria()->compare('status.status_id', $status);
    }
    else {
        $this->getDbCriteria()->addCondition('s.status_id IS NULL');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It contains some dirty work, because `withStatus()` uses `status` join subquery's data if `$status` is specified or base `s` alias if `$status` is null (it's because we're looking for user without record in `status` table). Maybe this is not most elegant solution, but works as it should.

Now I can use:

- `User::model()->findByPk(1)->status` to access specified user's status
- `User::model()->withStatus('active')->findAll()` list users with specified status (status may be passed as integer [`user_status.id`] or string [`status_dict.name`])
- `User::model()->withStatus(null)->count()` get number of users without any status

Answer (score 1):

I found somewhere else similar solution:

Scope function:

```
public function withStatus($status) {
    if(!is_numeric($status) && !is_null($status)) {
        $status = StatusDictionary::model()->find('lower(name)=lower(:name)', array(':name' => $status))->getAttribute('id');
    }

    $this->with('status');
    $this->getDbCriteria()->compare('i.statusId', $status);

    return $this;
}
```

Relations record (this join is protecting relation from filter criteria):

```
'status' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Status', 'clientId',
                'join' => 'INNER JOIN (select max(id) id from status group by clientId) j ON i.id=j.id',
                'alias' => 'i'
            ),
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is almost good solution - almost, because it does not return users without any status. However, your solution pushed me to check something and I found as it should be (I'll post the answer).